# is there a way for me to have a console in php like with node.js?

Tags: php, apache

Right now im hosting my php website on a server in the www folder of apache server. The problem with this is I have no console to check for errors. I was wondering if its possible for me to have a console with php like with node.js where you can console.log("message"). I know I can echo data on php with echo "message", but the problem with this is when the site crashes then I can't echo something.

Comment: Everything that you're asking for should be in the server's error logs.

Comment: When the site crashes? Your hosting provider or administrator could give you a link to check error logs for your installation. But if you need it for debugging during development... you may look at something like DebugBar https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar